# Concat n numbers of array into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

Suppose i have an object whose values are arrays just like this:

```
obj = {
    'key1': [1,2],
    'key2': [3,4],
    'key3': [5,6],
}
```

How to i merge all the arrays of the object into one using concat. The number of keys of the object is dynamic of course but it will have at least one instance
The desired output is this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) on [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is supposed to do the job:

```js
const obj = {
        key1: [1,2],
        key2: [3,4],
        key3: [5,6]
      },
      merged = Object.values(obj).flat()

console.log(merged)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

If being unlucky enough to deal with IE or Edge, one may fallback to `reduce()` for *flattening*:

```js
const obj = {
        key1: [1,2],
        key2: [3,4],
        key3: [5,6]
      },
      merged = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r,k){     
        return r.concat(obj[k])
      }, [])

console.log(merged)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Or flatMap, I think flat works on arrays only, but he has an object with array properties.

Comment: Beware of `flat` support though. Worth mentioning that, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj={ 'key1': [1,2], 'key2': [3,4], 'key3': [5,6] };

var result = Object.values(obj)
    .reduce((accum, values) => {
        accum.push(...values);
        return accum;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Yevgens answer is better.

Comment: This answer has better broswer support though, so if for some reason OP needs to support IE and/or Edge this answer would be the correct one.

Comment: If we consider IE we must replace the spread operator `...` to `concat()` so the result can be `return accum.concat(values);`

Comment: Or `[].concat(...Object.values(obj))` and skip `reduce` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume all the values of the object will an array you can make a `Object.values()` loop and concat each array.

```
const obj={
    'key1': [1,2],
    'key2': [3,4],
    'key3': [5,6],
};

const res = [];
for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
    res.push(...value);
}
/// res: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```